# Rule for calculating big-O plus example I can't figure out

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I have the following rule:

If $f$ is $O(g)$ for ${x\to\infty}$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = 0$ than also $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$

Then my text proceeds to give an example:

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3^x+x^2+x\sqrt{x^5}-\ln(x^2+1)}{2\cdot3^{x+1}-2^x+\sqrt{1+x^6}}$

And it says: "We will use the fact that the last three terms of the numerator are $O(x^4)$, and the fact that the last two terms of the denominator are $O(2^x)$". This is what happens next:

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3^x+O(x^4)}{2\cdot3^{x+1}+O(2^x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+O(\frac{x^4}{3^x})}{2\cdot3+O(\frac{2^x}{3^x})} = \frac{1}{6}$

I fail to see how the rule is used, because e.g. if $O(g)$ is $O(x^4)$, this does not equal zero. I also can't figure out what $f$ is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$O(x^4)$ doesn't tend to $0$, true, but the whole expression is $O(\frac{x^4}{3^x}$), which tends to 0 and hence the original expression too, because it's in fact $o(\frac{x^4}{3^x}$).

Comment: Yes, I just figured that one out too, $lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^4}{3^x} = 0$. But then my question is still, what here is $f$ then? I'm one step closer, but still confused :-) E.g., if the whole expression is $O(\frac{x^4}{3^x})$, why write $O(x^4)$ as a replacement for the expression in the beginning?

Comment: $f$ are the last 3 terms in the numerator that are $O(\cdot)$ this experssion

Comment: I'm a little confuddled about why the *whole* expression is $\frac{x^4}{3^x}$ and not $x^4$

Comment: ...because then you divide it through $3^x$.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Did not know that you could place the division in an $O$ notation. But I think that it has to do with what somebody else said - it is just making those last three terms fall under something simpler (x^4), and replace those terms with $x^4$ (then divide)

Comment: No, you $bound$ them by something that's $guaranteed$ to be asymptotically larger, and then divide by something else; together this guarantees you convergence to 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22095/discussion-between-garth-marenghi-and-alex).

Comment: I ammended my expression; I hope you can see the edits that I made. The *whole* thing does not go to $0$, it goes to $\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: I never said 'the whole thing' (?) converges to 0. The discussion was only about 3 terms in the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

$f = O(g)$ means that $f/g$ is eventually bounded. In your case, the author writes $x^{2} + x\sqrt{x^{5}} - \log (x^{2}+1)$ as $O(x^{4}),$ for the the former divided by $x^{4}$ is eventually bounded. For the same reason, the author also writes $-2^{x} + \sqrt{1 + x^{6}}$ as $O(2^{x})$.

Note in addition that convergence implies boundedness.

Note also that the point to use $o$ or $O$ notation is not too "calculate", but rather to preserve the essential information that matters in such a context. In your example, you find that using the $O$-notation greatly simplifies the work and helps one to catch the essentials.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. The thing that confuses me is that I get the idea that if $f$ is $O(g)$ for ${x\to\infty}$ and $lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) = 0$, that $g(x)$ would be the function $x^4$. I now see that it's $O(\frac{x^4}{3^x})$ that's headed to $0$, but I don't understand how you arrive there (why it's allowed)

Comment: Good! But as @Alex and I also pointed out, convergence implies boundedness, so $o(x^{4}/3^{x})$ is $O(x^{4}/3^{x}).$ Please note also that you have the right to upvote :)

Comment: Is that little-o? I unfortunately don't know anything about that yet.

Comment: $f(x) = o(g(x))$ means that $f(x)/g(x) \to 0$ as $x$ tends to specified destination. For example, if $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^{2}$ for $x > 0,$ then $f(x) = o(g(x)),$ for $x/x^{2} = 1/x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty.$ Since convergence implies boundedness, and you know the rest. :)

Comment: Don't be stingy in upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Here $f$ is $\frac{x^2+x^{\frac{7}{2}}- \ln (x^2+1)}{3^x}$ and $g$ is $\frac{x^4}{3^x}$ for the numerator. Why the system ask me whether i'm a human being?

Comment: Your first sentence gave me some more clarity. The second one added some clouds. What?

Comment: When i post my answers, the system asked me whether i'm a human being frequently and also asked me to check the CAP...(?I can't remember it) box. So I ask you, maybe you encountered the situation and know how to solve it. It doesn't related to the mathematical problem.

Comment: CAPTCHA? I have no idea... I've only ran into it here on this site but very, very rarely, and I also don't have an idea as to why it happens.

Comment: Yes, it is. It doesn't matter. Thank you.